# countable zeros of a particular solution to some 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation$: \ e^xx^2y''-e^xxy'+(x^2-1)y=0.$ Suppose $f:(-\infty,0) \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $(1-x^2)f(x)=e^x(x^2f''(x)-xf'(x)), \forall x\in (-\infty,0).$

If $f$ is not a constant function, could anyone advise me how to show it must have countably infinite zeros in $(-\infty,0)$ such that $0>\alpha_1> \alpha_2>...$ and $\text{lim}_{i \to \infty}(\alpha_i-\alpha_{i+1})=0,$ where $\{\alpha_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are zeros of $f \ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you very much.